# Angular: this.div.nativeElement is empty once sent to an API

Tags: angular

I retrieve the html of a div in order to send it to my API just like this :

```
  @ViewChild('box-list') div: ElementRef;

GetContainerText() {
    const html = this.div.nativeElement;
    this.sendingHTMLService
    .sendHTML(
      html
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
          console.log(successfully');
      }
    });
  }
```

When i console log the HTML retrieved i get what i want :
[image]

but in my api i get an empty object, the `expression $body` has as `value {"html":{}}`

Here is my service:

```
  sendHTML(html: any) {
    console.log(html);
    return this.http.post<any>(
      '/api/sendHTML',
      { html},
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

When i try sending an html code from postman i get the desired result in my `$body`, i send the body request like this in postman:

```
{
  "html": '<div _ngcontent-hab-c1="" class="box" style="max-width: 800px; ...'
}
```

Once i tried to do the same and send the html retrieved to my API between two `''` like this :

```
  sendHTML(html: any) {
    console.log(html);
    return this.http.post<any>(
      '/api/sendHTML',
      { html: '' + html + ''},
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

I don't get an empty object anymore but i get :

```
{"html":"[object HTMLDivElement]"}
```

Comment: You're trying to send an HTMLElement object. What do you actually want to send to your API? If you want to send HTML text, then get the innerHTML (ou outerHTML) of the element, and send that.

Comment: `this.div.nativeElement.innerHTML` or `this.div.nativeElement.outerHTML`, not sure html or HTML, or Html

Comment: Oh yes it worked i was only passing this.div.nativeElement, it worked with the innerHTML. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to get the HTML code of the element.

If that's the case, then you need to get the `outerHTML` property of your element.